# Django: what is the right href to individual url?

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Post`. Each individual post extends `post_detail.html` and has it's own url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('news/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='news_page'),
...
]
```

The model consists of title, description, image etc. On `main.html` I show the title and the image of the last post, the second last post, and the third last post. My `views.py` looks like

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'html/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        kwargs['last_post'] = posts[0]
        kwargs['second_last_post'] = posts[1]
        kwargs['third_last_post'] = posts[2]
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Here I have the title of the last and the second last post in my template:

`<h5 href="#">{{ last_post.title }}</h5>`

`<h5 href="#">{{ second_last_post.title }}</h5>`

Now I want to connect these titles to their own urls. I mean when I click on the title of the last post in `main.html` I want to open individual url of that post. How can I do that?

Comment: Note that you might get an error if there are not enough posts in the db. As a next step, try adding `posts[:3]` (a slice of the first three posts) to the template context, then loop through with `{% for post in posts %}`. You might also prefer to use `TemplateView` instead of `ListView`, because you aren't really using `ListView`'s features at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

As a first step you can use the pk to construct the URL:

```
<h5 href="/news/{{ last_post.pk }}">{{ last_post.title }}</h5>
```

Next, you can use the `url` tag

```
<h5 href="{% url 'news_page' last_post.pk %}">{{ last_post.title }}</h5>
```

Finally, if you define a [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method,

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news_page', args=[self.pk])
```

then you can use it in the template:

```
<h5 href="{{ last_post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ last_post.title }}</h5>
```

Finally a note about namespaces: you haven't shown your full URL config, but if you are using a namespace, e.g. `app_name='posts'`, then you will need to include the namespace when reversing the URL, e.g. `{% url posts:news_page last_post.pk %}` of `reverse('posts:news_page', args=[self.pk])`.